# What files shall I store in Git and which ones I'd better not?

Tags: eclipse, git

I created a new *Dynamic Web Project* in Eclipse and did nothing more.

Now I do the initial commit.

The following files can be committed:

[image]

I feel that none of these files are needed in Git - am I right?

And how to prevent these files from appearing again in this menu window.

Comment: `.gitignore` have to be shared, `MANIFEST.MF` is part of your project and the rest are project specific Eclipse settings. Using project specific settings but not sharing them does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

- Any file that you create should be in.
- Any file that is generated (by: tools, compiler etc) should be out.

Pay attention to file indirectly generated by your action (IDE project file). Some of these should be in, to share working environment across computers.

Create a git-repo then use another PC (with same tools) and pull, you should be able to work the same way.

Comment: The folder(s) containing generated (in Eclipse called _derived_) files are automatically added to `.gitignore` (this is why there is the file `.gitignore`). Only project specific settings to share are stored in the project. Not sharing these files means you have different settings/configuration on different computer, e.g. different settings for the formatter, etc.

Comment: Yes .gitignore should be in version control